# Changing SPI clock speed for DotStar LEDs connected to ESP32

Tags: arduino, led, spi, esp32

I'm using an ESP32 with a strip of DotStar RGB LEDs that I'd like to control. I'm using the library's strand_test code example to verify my breadboard connections (I am using a level translator to produce 5V compatible signals) but the LEDs are not working. Since my breadboard is very noisy, I'd like to try lowering the SPI clock rate to see if this helps, But I'm not sure of the simplest way to do this. From reviewing the Adafruit library, it looks like they are implementing the SPI protocol using a custom, platform-independent library. Do I need to edit the library code directly to make the change or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: What level translator are you using? Why do you say your breadboard is noisy?  Post a schematic.

Comment: Adafruit libraries usually can use hardware SPI or built-in 'softwares SPI'. for hardware SPI you can set the speed with SPI.setClockDivider if the library doesn't use SPI transactions. if the library uses SPI transactions, then find the definition of the transaction and change the clock divider setting